# On measurability in Wiener space

Tags: measure-theory, wiener-measure

Let $f$ be a complex-valued continuous function on Wiener space such that $|f|$ is measurable. Is $f$ then measurable, too? I am looking for a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous then it's certainly measurable, no further assumptions needed, assuming you mean measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Did you mean to write something else?

Comment: @NateEldredge; Where can I find a detailed argument? I mean the sigma algebra with respect to which the Gaussian measure is defined.

Comment: Classical Wiener measure, on the space of continuous functions, is defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (or its completion).  And every continuous function is measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  This is completely trivial and there really are no details: under a continuous function, the preimage of every open set is open and hence Borel, so the function is measurable.